# Prove a given collection of operators is invariant on every subspace of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need to prove the following theorem and am quite lost, especially in proving the dimensions of the subspaces:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. let $C_2$ be the collection of linear operators $\{I, T\}$ on $V$ such that $T\neq I$ and $T^2= I$. Then there is always a way to express $V$ as a direct sum of subspaces $V=U_1\oplus U_2 \oplus ...\oplus U_m$ such that $C_2$ is invariant on each subspace. If our vector space is over the field $\mathbb F=\mathbb R $ then each subspace is of dimension at most 2.

Comment: Hint: If $v\in V$, $v\neq 0$, then either $T(v)\in\mathrm{span}(v)$ or $T(v)\notin \mathrm{span}(v)$. In the former case, is $\mathrm{span}(v)$ invariant? In the latter case, what happens when you look at $\mathrm{span}(v,T(v))$?

Comment: In the former case, $span(v)$ is invariant. I'm not sure about the latter. I guess I'm confused as to how, if each subspace of the direct sum is unique, the subspaces can share the same elements.

Comment: They don’t; they intersect trivially; but what does that have to do with anything? In any case, you seem to have ignored one of your hypotheses, so use it...

Comment: If I can show that $V=span(v)\oplus span(v, T(v))$ then I've proved it?

Comment: If you can show that, you can show that Mathematics is inconsistent, because it’s false. That’s not the point. You are looking for invariant subspaces.